# Edit Azure function deployed from Source Control

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've got some Azure functions that I deployed from source control. Sometimes, when working on them, it is easier to just edit them in the portal then copy/paste that back in to my source controlled code, but the portal doesn't allow editing form a source-controlled function by default, however it does say that you can change this in function.json.

I browsed the Azure Functions documentation and also the WebJobs SDK source on Github but can't find what this value is that can be used to allow portal editing of the source-controlled function.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no way to do this right now, but we're going to add a way to override the behavior (basically, a button that says, "I know what I'm doing, let me edit). Please watch this GitHub issue: [Add a way to allow editing even if CD is configured](https://github.com/projectkudu/AzureFunctionsPortal/issues/366)

In the meantime, you can edit in the App Service Editor in another browser tab. Browse to yourfunctionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev, or go to Function App Settings -> App Service Settings -> App Service Editor.

Comment: With the release of Azure Functions 2.0 into GA, has this been resolved any further since 2016? Using NodeJS, I don't seem to be able to edit in cloud today.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like MS has changed it again a bit :)

In the Azure Portal, Go to **Function App** | **App Service Editor (Preview)** under Development Tools | Click on **Go** (in the right-hand side pane). This will launch App Service Editor in the new tab. Look for your function and expand it to view the **.json**, **.ps1** and **other files**.

[image]